# how to return the value inside PromiseResult

Tags: reactjs, promise

I will try to keep my problem as simple as possible, I have this function that I created:

```
get_total_by_status(status: string){
  const total = imports.index(status).then((d) => {
    return d.total 
})
  return total
}
```

and I'm calling this function like this:

```
var status_published = this.get_total_by_status("pending payment")
```

but it's not working, I have put a console.log(total) inside the function, and I got this:

```
Promise {<pending>}
  [[Prototype]]:Promise
  [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
  [[PromiseResult]]: 202
```

how can I return the 202 value??

I know that there are tons of questions similar to this one, and basically, all of them tell me to add async() at the function, and a await on the moment I call the function, I have tried this without success, and I have no idea what I'm missing here, I'm a python programer with 0 knowledge in react

Edit:

Tried this approach, still can't return the value

```
get_total_by_status(status: string, onSuccess) {
  imports.index(status).then(
    (d) => {
      onSuccess(d.total);
    }
  );
}

# STUFFF

const status_published = this.get_total_by_status("published", 
(response) => {
      return response  //also tried status_published = response
    })
```

if I place a console.log(response) I do indeed can log the 202 that I was expecting, but **status_published** keeps being null

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

Option 1. Wrap your `get_total_by_status` call in an async function and await your `get_total_by_status` to get resolved value as follows:

```js
async function get_total_by_status(status) {
  const total = imports.index(status).then(
    (d) => {
      return d.total;
    }
  );
  return total;
}

async function getPromiseValue() {
  let status_published = await get_total_by_status("My status");
  console.log(status_published);
}

getPromiseValue(); // prints "My status"
```

Option 2. Another option would be pass callback to your `get_total_by_status` function as an argument and call that callback in `.then()` block as follows:

```js
function get_total_by_status(status, onSuccess) {
  // you don't need to store any return value in this case
  imports.index(status).then(
    (d) => {
      onSuccess(d.total);
    }
  );
}

get_total_by_status("My status", (response) => {
  console.log(response); // prints "My status"
});
```

Let me know if you have any kind of query or doubt regarding above code snippets :)

Comment: So I tried to assign response to a variable, but still falling to the same issue:

Comment: Can you update your code with the new one? I also think callback approach is good to be considered.